# c# - ObservableCollection doesn't seem save added items

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, win-universal-app, observablecollection

### Description

I'm trying to build this simple UWP MVVM notetaking app.
The purpose of the app is adding text from a `Textbox` to a `ListView`, when a ***Add*** `Button` is clicked, or delete an item of the `ListView` by pressing a ***Delete*** `Button`, which is assigned to each item in the `ListView`.

### Adding item to the ObservableCollection

Adding items to the `ObservableCollection<Note>` seems to work fine. The items are shown in the `ListView` without any problems.

### Deleting items in the ObservableCollection

Deleting item doesn't work as it should.

#### My debug attempt

I tried to invoke the method responsible for deleting the items from both the constructor and the ***Delete*** `Button`.
When I invoke `DoDeleteNote(Note itemToDelete)` from the ***Delete*** `Button`, nothing happens, but if i invoke the same method from the constructor then the item is deleted.

I created a breakpoint in the `DoDeleteNote(Note itemToDelete)` method, and I can see in the debugger that it runs through the code, but nothing is deleted from the `ObservableCollection<Note>`.
However when i invoke the `DoDeleteNote(Note itemToDelete)` method from the constructor the item is deleted.

It is also strange, that the **Note** items I create and add to the `ObservableCollection<Note>` from the **NoteViewModel** constructor are the only items that are in the `ObservableCollection<Note>`. The items I add using the ***Add*** `Button`, are gone, but still shown in the `ListView`.

I’m thinking maybe something is wrong with either `INotifyPropertyChanged` or the bindings, but i’m not sure where to start looking, and what to look for, so I could use some help.

*I know there seems to be a lot of code here, but I felt it was necessary not to omit anything to understand the data flow.*

#### XAML

```
<Page
    x:Class="ListView2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ListView2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewModel="using:ListView2.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid.DataContext>
        <viewModel:NoteViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <ListView  Header="Notes"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Height="341"
               Width="228"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Margin="163,208,0,0"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Notes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="MyDataTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <TextBlock x:Name="TbxblListItem" Text="{Binding NoteText}"/>

                    <Button Command="{Binding DeleteNoteCommand}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TbxblListItem}">
                        <Button.DataContext>
                            <viewModel:NoteViewModel/>
                        </Button.DataContext>
                        <Button.Content>
                            <SymbolIcon Symbol="Delete" 
                                        ToolTipService.ToolTip="Delete Note" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <TextBox x:Name="TbxNoteContent" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Margin="571,147,0,0"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="376"/>

    <Button Content="Add"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="597,249,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Command="{Binding AddNoteCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=TbxNoteContent}"/>
</Grid>
</page>
```

#### Note

```
namespace ListView2.Model
{
    class Note
    {
        private string _noteText;

        public Note(string noteText)
        {
            NoteText = noteText;
        }

        public string NoteText { get { return _noteText; } set { _noteText = value; } }
    }
}
```

#### Notification

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ListView2.Model
{
    class Notification : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

#### NoteViewModel

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using ListView2.Model;

namespace ListView2.ViewModel
{
    class NoteViewModel : Notification
    {
        #region Instance Fields
        private ObservableCollection<Note> _notes;
        private RelayCommand _addNoteCommand;
        private RelayCommand _deleteNoteCommand;
        //private string _noteText;
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public NoteViewModel()
        {
            //adds sample data to Notes property (ObservableCollection<Note>)
            Notes = new ObservableCollection<Note>() { new Note("Sample text 1"), new Note("Sample text 2") };

            //Used for testing the deletion of items from ObservableCollection-------------------------------------
            Notes.RemoveAt(1);
            Notes.Add(new Note("Sample text 3"));
            //foreach (var item in Notes)
            //{
            //    if (item.NoteText == "Sample text 3")
            //    {
            //        DoDeleteNote(item);
            //        break;
            //    }
            //}
            //------------------------------------------------------

            //Button command methods are added to delegates
            AddNoteCommand = new RelayCommand(DoAddNote);
            DeleteNoteCommand = new RelayCommand(DoDeleteNote);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public ObservableCollection<Note> Notes { get { return _notes; } set { _notes = value; OnPropertyChanged("Notes"); } }

        //public string NoteText { get { return _noteText; } set { _noteText = value; OnPropertyChanged("NoteText"); } }

        public RelayCommand AddNoteCommand { get { return _addNoteCommand; } set { _addNoteCommand = value; } }

        public RelayCommand DeleteNoteCommand { get { return _deleteNoteCommand; } set { _deleteNoteCommand = value; } }

        #endregion

        #region methods

        private void DoAddNote(object obj)
        {
            var newItem = obj as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newItem))
            {
                AddNote(newItem);
            }
        }

        //Work in progress
        private void DoDeleteNote(object obj)
        {
            //Used when the XAML Delete Button invokes this method
            TextBlock textBlockSender = obj as TextBlock;
            //string myString = textBlockSender.Text;
            Note itemToDelete = textBlockSender.DataContext as Note;

            //Used when the constuctor invokes this method, for testing purposes------------
            //Note itemToDelete = obj as Note;
            //--------------------------------------------------------

            foreach (Note note in this.Notes)
            {
                if (note.NoteText == itemToDelete.NoteText)
                {
                    //int noteIndex = Notes.IndexOf(note);
                    //Notes.RemoveAt(noteIndex);
                    DeleteNote(note);
                    break;
                }
            }
            //if (Notes.Contains(itemToDelete))
            //{
            //    Notes.Remove(itemToDelete);
            //}
        }

        public void AddNote(string noteText)
        {
            this.Notes.Add(new Note(noteText));
        }

        public void DeleteNote(Note itemToDelete)
        {
            this.Notes.Remove(itemToDelete);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

RelayCommand class which is the implementation for ICommand does not seem relevant for the question, so I haven't included it here, but if you are curious it can be seen on [GitHub](https://github.com/chmodder/UWPListView2.git)

Comment: Are you sure that you get the `itemToDelete` in your `Note itemToDelete = textBlockSender.DataContext as Note;`? And if you get it, then are you sure that it is the note in `Notes` - `this.Notes.Contains(note)`?

Comment: I just tried debugging again, and the item does get deleted, from the `ObservableCollection<Note>` in `DoDeleteNote()`method, but it seems like the 2  **Note** objects that are created in the constructor have been recreated every time I step through the `DoAddNote()` or `DoDeleteNote()`, like the ObservableCollection has been reset. Does the Xaml code somehow instantiate NoteViewModel multiple times, so the `ObservableCollection<Note>` is reset? I think maybe it has to do with the DataContext in the Delete Button, but i'm not really sure.

Comment: I have just noticed `                        <Button.DataContext>
                            <viewModel:NoteViewModel/>
                        </Button.DataContext>` That's the thing that actually creates **a new NoteViewModel** for each actual viewmodel in your collection. And that `NoteViewModel` is obviously not in the `this.Notes` collection. The actual item will propagate to the DataTemplate's DataContext automatically - there is no need to do anything special.

Comment: I added that `<DataContext>` to the `<Button>`, to be able to bind the `<Button Command >` to the `DeleteNoteCommand`, because the `ListView ItemsSource`points to **Notes**, so the `<TextBox>` can use the **Note** property, and the `<Button>` can only bind to the same items as the `<TextBox>`, since they are inside the same `<ListView>`. I'm not really sure how to work around that issue, since MVVM and XAML is new to me, but it seems that we found the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Eugene Podskal points out one of the problems is with this code

```
<Button.DataContext>
    <viewModel:NoteViewModel/>
</Button.DataContext>
```

Your Layout Grid instantiates a new `NoteViewModel` and the above code will do the same leaving you with 2 NoteViewModels active on the page.

Firstly give the ListView a name

```
<ListView x:Name="MyList" Header="Notes"
```

Next let's fix the Bindings on your `DataTemplate` of ListView `MyList`

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate x:Name="MyDataTemplate">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <TextBlock x:Name="TbxblListItem" Text="{Binding NoteText}"/>
         <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteNoteCommand, ElementName=MyList}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding}">                            
         <SymbolIcon Symbol="Delete" 
            ToolTipService.ToolTip="Delete Note" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Button>
     </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

this line

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteNoteCommand, ElementName=MyList}"
```

means we are now Binding to the `DataContext` of `MyList` which is your `NoteViewModel` as defined under the main `Grid`

The `CommandParamter` is simplified to

```
CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

as I explain below it is better practice to Bind to the object in your `MyList` which in this case is an object of `Note`

To make this work we need to adjust your `NoteViewModel` slightly
Change your private delete field and public property to

```
private RelayCommand<Note> _deleteNoteCommand;
public RelayCommand<Note> DeleteNoteCommand { get { return _deleteNoteCommand; } set { _deleteNoteCommand = value; } }
```

and in the constructor

```
DeleteNoteCommand = new RelayCommand<Note>(DoDeleteNote);
```

`DoDeleteNote` method is simplified to

```
private void DoDeleteNote(Note note)
{
    this.Notes.Remove(note);    
}
```

so we handily get rid of casting from a `TextBlock`. You can now get rid of the `DeleteNote` method as it's no longer needed.

Finally we need to add a new `RelayCommand` that takes a Generic Type to make our Command `DeleteNoteCommand` work correctly.

**RelayCommand**

```
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    private readonly Action<T> _execute = null;
    private readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute = null;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command with conditional execution.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
    }


    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Apologies this answer is long but I wanted to point out every step. I also suggest using a mvvm framework when working with xaml as it will make your life alot easier. I recommend [mvvmlight](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) but there are plenty of others. Hope that helps

Comment: Don't apologize for making the answer long. I like the level of details in your explanation. I was actually wondering how to reach the other properties from the <ListView>,when `ItemsSource` was already set to **Notes**, as I realized myself, that by using `DataContext` 2 times actually creates 2 objects of **NoteViewModel**, and that the constructor then creates a new `ObservableCollection` that resets the values in the previous one. `{Binding DataContext.DeleteNoteCommand ElementName= MyList}` was exactly what I was looking for. I'm now able to delete the list elements.

Comment: Excellent glad it helped :)

Comment: I also like how you cleaned my code by removing the `DeleteNote()` method. I haven't implemented that last part yet, as I need study your code a little bit more to fully understand it, since I just heard about ICommand and delegates last week, so it's all still a new concept for me, but it looks a way more smarter method to pass the data from the `ListView` element. Thanks for spending time on this great answer.

Comment: no problem delegates take a while to get your head around (Im still trying after a few years lol) but once you understand the code above moving onto a framework like mvvm light will be easier as you've got the concepts nailed down.